# Realizar una función llamada catalogar() que reciba la lista de vehiculos y los recorra mostrando el nombre de su clase y sus atributos

Tags: python

Estoy frente a un ejercicio que no me acaba de salir.
La cosa es que tengo que crear una función catalogar para que cuando me imprima por pantalla me salga algo parecido a esto:
[nombre de la instancia: diccionario con sus atributos]. He pensado de inicializarlo en el mismo init pero no sé como hacerlo. Se que tengo que usar el type(objeto).**name** pero no se como va.

Después me piden que esta misma función reciba un argumento optativo ruedas con unos valores en concreto y que me imprima por pantalla esos objetos que contengan esa cantidad de ruedas.

```
class Vehiculo():
    counter = 0
    color = ""
    ruedas = 0
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas):
        self.color=color
        self.ruedas=ruedas  
        
           

class Coche(Vehiculo): 
    velocidad = 0
    cilindrada = 0
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas, velocidad, cilindrada):
        super().__init__(color, ruedas)
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada

    
class Bicicleta(Vehiculo): 
    tipo = ""
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas, tipo):
        super().__init__(color, ruedas)
        self.tipo = tipo
      
        
class Camioneta(Coche):
    carga = 0
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas, velocidad, cilindrada, carga):
        super().__init__(color, ruedas, velocidad, cilindrada)
        self.carga = carga
        


class Motocicleta(Bicicleta): 
    velocidad = 0
    cilindrada = 0
    def __init__(self,color, ruedas, tipo, velocidad, cilindrada):
        super().__init__(color, ruedas,tipo)
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada
        
        
a = Camioneta("marron",8, 120, 400, 500)
b = Coche("verde",4, 120, 800)
c = Bicicleta("azul",2,"triciclo")
d = Coche("verde",4, 120, 800)
e = Motocicleta("azul",2,"triciclo",150, 200)
lista_vehiculos = [a.__dict__,b.__dict__,c.__dict__,d.__dict__,e.__dict__]
print(lista_vehiculos)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución:

```
def catalogar(lista):
    for vehiculo in lista:
        print(type(vehiculo).__name__, vehiculo.__dict__)
```

La función recibe una lista de vehiculos y los recorre uno a uno con `for`.

La función `type(vehiculo)` retorna la clase original del vehículo, de la cual quiero extraer su nombre, que está almacenado en el atributo `__name__`. Por tanto

```
type(vehiculo).__name__
```

es la clase Python y

```
vehiculo.__dict__
```

son los atributos del vehiculo en particular.

#### Demo

Ojo: Tienes un error conceptual en tu código. La lista de vehiculos es

```
lista_vehiculos = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

Lo que tienes originalmente es una lista de diccionarios.

Ojo: Estas declarando atributos de clase que son innecesarios. Los elimine.

```
class Vehiculo():
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas):
        self.color = color
        self.ruedas = ruedas


class Coche(Vehiculo):
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas, velocidad, cilindrada):
        super().__init__(color, ruedas)
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada


class Bicicleta(Vehiculo):
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas, tipo):
        super().__init__(color, ruedas)
        self.tipo = tipo


class Camioneta(Coche):
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas, velocidad, cilindrada, carga):
        super().__init__(color, ruedas, velocidad, cilindrada)
        self.carga = carga


class Motocicleta(Bicicleta):
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas, tipo, velocidad, cilindrada):
        super().__init__(color, ruedas, tipo)
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada

def catalogar(lista):
    for vehiculo in lista:
        print(type(vehiculo).__name__, vehiculo.__dict__)

a = Camioneta("marron", 8, 120, 400, 500)
b = Coche("verde", 4, 120, 800)
c = Bicicleta("azul", 2, "triciclo")
d = Coche("rosado", 4, 150, 800)
e = Motocicleta("azul", 2, "triciclo", 150, 200)
lista_vehiculos = [a, b, c, d, e]
catalogar(lista_vehiculos)
```

produce:

```
Camioneta {'color': 'marron', 'ruedas': 8, 'velocidad': 120, 'cilindrada': 400, 'carga': 500}
Coche {'color': 'verde', 'ruedas': 4, 'velocidad': 120, 'cilindrada': 800}
Bicicleta {'color': 'azul', 'ruedas': 2, 'tipo': 'triciclo'}
Coche {'color': 'rosado', 'ruedas': 4, 'velocidad': 150, 'cilindrada': 800}
Motocicleta {'color': 'azul', 'ruedas': 2, 'tipo': 'triciclo', 'velocidad': 150, 'cilindrada': 200}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Estoy empezando y lo que me parece muy complicado, no lo es una vez lo entiendes.